# dhcpd leased a permanent address - why?

Tags: ip, dhcp, ubuntu-server, dhcp-server

I'm using isc-dchp-server on my home network. Today my only desktop client wasn't able to recieve an IP address from the dhcpd server, which is strange because it has a reserved address in dhcpd.conf:

```
host Livingroom-PC {
hardware ethernet 00:22:4D:6B:AA:6F;
fixed-address 192.168.88.150;
}
```

Syslog said:

```
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.88.150 (192.168.88.100) from 00:22:4d:6b:aa:6f via br0
DHCPACK on 192.168.88.150 to 00:22:4d:6b:aa:6f via br0
Abandoning IP address 192.168.88.150: declined.
```

I checked the dhcpd.leases and IP was leased to another client without any trace of it's MAC address:

```
lease 192.168.88.150 {
  starts 1 2023/03/20 07:25:33;
  ends 2 2023/03/21 07:48:23;
  tstp 2 2023/03/21 07:32:12;
  cltt 1 2023/03/20 07:25:33;
  binding state abandoned;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
}
server-duid "\000\001\000\001+\252\313\307\000!Z\025#v";
```

I pinged the reserved address 192.168.88.150 and it responded. I retrieved its MAC address (14:49:E0:0C:28:D2) and it's total different from the one I entered for my desktop PC to have a fixed address.

How is it possible? I'm using this setup since years and never had any problem with that. What am I missing here?

Comment: To me this looks like your intended device got its intended lease, and then sent a DHCPDECLINE to the server to abandon its lease. Maybe the impostor started squatting on the IP address (or doing something like *proxy ARP* that might make the address seem occupied), so the intended device decided to abandon it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's strange anyway. The 'impostor' is a 10 years old Samsung TV, and the 'victim' is a simple WIn10 box. What do you think, can I dig deeper to find out the root cause?